# which IOS browser support to access camera and ble service?

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to access the camera and BLE service from ios device but I am not able to access them. So anyone suggests to me any browser or any script where I can access it.

Thanks.

Comment: For BLE try [Bluefy](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/bluefy-web-ble-browser/id1492822055). The official [Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API#browser_compatibility) does not state an iOS browser which is compatible in their compatibility list though

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Bluefly does not support a pair of Bluetooth devices. I am not getting a Bluetooth devices when pair.

Comment: There is also [WebBLE](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/webble/id1193531073) but the feedback on the AppStore is not that great. Other than that or in regards of the camera access I'm not able to help you further

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan No Problem. Thanks for your help.